# Language settings are not visible

Tags: language

I installed SharePoint Language Pack but I can't see the 'Language Settings' link under Site Administration.

From CA I can see that the pack is installed without problems, no errors, no critical issues...

Any ideas?

Comment: Which language pack? (sounds obvious, but if you had just installed US English no other others [as a practice run], then no extra options appear anywhere).

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4731 This is the one I installed and I suppose it has support for various languages.

Comment: Ah ok, disregard my comment then :)

Comment: Actually, I believe you need to select the language from the dropdown on that page (default is set to English). It's confusing, because the UI language of that page changes too when you change the selection of the dropdown! For each language, you need to download and configure an individual language pack.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a link on the dropdown. The package I downloaded supports all the languages I suppose. So no need to download individual packages for each language.

Comment: I know this question is quite old now, but worth correcting - you _MUST_ download a different language pack for each language that you wish to support. SharePoint 2010 support dozens of languages, and each language pack is 200+ MB, so it's not feasible to provide a single package for all languages. To download, follow the link above, select the language you wish to download, wait for the page to refresh, and then click the Download button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step by Step instruction to install and configure language pack for SharePoint 2010.
http://virtualizesharepoint.com/2011/07/21/installing-language-packs-for-sharepoint-2010/

[image]

[image]
Once the configuration is completed, navigate Central Administration -> Upgrade and Migration –>
Check product and patch installation status.

[image]
Now Open the SharePoint site -> Site Settings -> Site Administration -> Language Settings

Comment: I think the package I downloaded doesn't include French so that's the problem. It includes, by default, English support so I don't see any language preference anywhere. Product installation status shows that the package is installed.

Comment: Oh, I love an answer that includes a dead link and no explanation.